# How to overwrite a local repository from more than one remote repo?

Tags: git, powershell

I have some trouble with git. I have a few powershell scripts that create a local git repository from remote.
In my scripts I test if a remote repository is already linked to the local repo.

```
$Repository = &git remote -v
Write-Host("Standard Repo laden...")
try
{
    if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Repository)))
    {        
        &git init
        &git remote set-url origin $Standard_Repository 
    }
    else
    {
        &git remote add origin $Standard_Repository
    }
    &git remote update origin --prune
    &git fetch origin
    &git checkout origin
}
```

Problem is, when a remote repository already is assigned to the local repository the other remotes will not be added as remote and git wouldn't fetch the files from the remotes.

The remote repositories will never get updated from local.

Can you help me out with this one? As you maybe have noticed I'm not used to the git language.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you already have a remote named `origin`, use a new name for next remote.

Comment: @ElpieKay Tried it, doesn't work. Additionally I added code to remove the remote ```git remote rm $remoteRepo``` but it also made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. For each remote repository I now create a separate local repository. This does the work.